# Baby Rudin Chapter $4$ Exercise $1$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

Suppose $f$ is a real function which satisfies $\lim\limits_{  h\to0}[f(x+h)-f(x-h)]=0$ for every $x$.

Does this imply that $f$ is continuous? Through trial and error I realized this is false but I am not sure that my reasoning is correct. I thought that one could simply consider a constant function that is not defined at some point $p$. But then I realized it could be incorrect to split this limit into $\lim\limits_{  h\to0}[f(x+h)]- \lim\limits_{  h\to0}[f(x-h)]=0$. As $x$ is fixed, use the point $x=p$ and we get $c-c = 0$ and the condition is satisfied for all $x$, but $f$ is not continuous at $p$ by definition. Is there something wrong with my thinking? Could this reasoning be correct even without splitting the limit?

Comment: Your counterexample (a function that is some constant value $c$ everywhere except one point where it takes a value $c' \ne c$) works fine.

Comment: But is my reasoning correct? I am not sure that this condition can be deduced for all $x$ without being able to split the limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed false, but not quite for the reason you state.  It need not be true that $f$ is undefined somewhere.  Consider the example $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1, & x = 2 \\ -1, & x \ne 2. \end{cases}$$  Then for every $x$, there is a choice $\epsilon > 0$ such that for every $0 < h < \epsilon$, $x+h \ne 2$ and $x-h \ne 2$. Consequently $$f(x+h) = f(x-h) = -1$$ and their difference is zero, but $f$ is not continuous everywhere.  In short, it is not the fact that $f$ is undefined at the point of discontinuity, but rather, that in any sufficiently small neighborhood of $x$, the limiting behavior need not be the same as the value at the discontinuity.

Comment: Yes, I believe there are counterexamples without needing to construct a function with an undefined point. But am I interested if the reasoning is sound.

Comment: @DerekLuna No, you may not split the limit.  In fact, you do not need to.  For example, if $x = 2$ in my example, for *every* choice of $h > 0$, $f(x+h) = f(x-h) = -1$, thus $f(x+h) - f(x-h) = 0$ **identically**, even without considering the limit.  Only when you choose $x \ne 2$ do you need to modify the argument to be more careful; e.g., if $x = 2.01$, then you must choose $h < 0.01$ in order for $f(x+h) = f(x-h) = -1$ for all such $h$, since $h = 0.01$ would result in $x-h = 2$, for just that one value.

Comment: I am not sure why I thought it was necessary. Thank you.